# Ember Cannot load a double nested route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm working on an ember js app, right now, and have an app with routes structured thus:

```
App.Router.reopen({
    rootURL: '/gui/'
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("about", { path: "about"})
    this.resource("tenant", { path: ":id" }, function() {
        this.resource("dossier", { path: "dossiers/:id"}, function() {
            this.resource("resource", { path: "resources/:id"}, function() {
                this.resource("service", { path: "services/:id"});
            });
        });
    })
});
```

Now, on the deepest level model (services), when I try to load a service up by typing the URL, it fails. So, if I go to, for example, 
`http://localhost:8080/gui#/8080/dossiers/8080/resources/8080/services/8080`, I get an error:

```
Assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.
```

I thought, perhaps it was a problem with the code I have generating the model, but I stripped all that code out, leaving model as a bare function, just to see, and it still gives this error. If I REMOVE the model code from the route altogether, though, it will load the page without complaining. So, this:

```
App.ServiceRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {},
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('service', {
            into: 'application'
        });
        this.render()
    }
});
```

raises an error. As does the original code:

```
App.ServiceRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        tenantModel = this.modelFor('tenant');
        dossierModel = this.modelFor('dossier');
        resourceModel = this.modelFor('resource');
        dossier_url = "/api/" + tenantModel.id + "/dossier/" + dossierModel.tag
        url = dossier_url + "/resources/" + resourceModel.name + "/services/" + params.id
        return jQuery.getJSON(url).then(function(data){
            data
        });
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('service', {
            into: 'application'
        });
        this.render()
    }
});
```

But, if I take the model out like this:

```
App.ServiceRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('service', {
            into: 'application'
        });
        this.render()
    }
});
```

Then the error disappears.

And here's the weirdest part.

If I load a different page, and just navigate into the services page... it works. It loads the model just fine. Its just if I try to refresh the page, or drop the url for a service straight into the browser, that it barfs out.

I read all kinds of internet posts on this error, but none seemed to match the situation I'm seeing - tried tweaking this and that, still nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the following can make it work:

```
App.ServiceRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        tenantModel = this.modelFor('tenant');
        dossierModel = this.modelFor('dossier');
        resourceModel = this.modelFor('resource');
        dossier_url = "/api/" + tenantModel.id + "/dossier/" + dossierModel.tag
        url = dossier_url + "/resources/" + resourceModel.name + "/services/" + params.id

        var promise = Ember.Deferred.create();
       jQuery.getJSON(url).then(function(data){
            promise.resolve(data);
        });

        return promise;
    },
    ....
});
```

Some remarks regarding your problems:

**Why does it say: "Assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object."?**

In your example the implementation of the model hook does not do anything. So the return value is undefined. After calling the model hook Ember seems to try to update the URL again. Your mapping says it should do that with the id of the routes model. So it tries to get the id property of your undefined object.

**Why does it work when navigating to the services page?**

I guess in this case you are supplying a model to your route with a `{{link-to}}` helper or a call to `transitionTo`. If you are supplying a model, then the model hook of your route does not need to be called. And when you enter your App via URL, the model hook has to be executed.

**How does my solution work?**

You are doing an asynchronous call to via jQuery.getJSON. This request has not finished when your code is reaching the end of the model hook and therefore again returns undefined. I instead return a promise. Ember is waiting for this promise to be resolved. I am resolving it in the callback of jQuery.getJSON.

**PS:** I am not sure wether your call to jQuery.getJSON is correct. Doesn't it have to call the success function. But i am not jquery expert and this might be completely wrong :-)

Comment: Boy is my face red - I should have seen that. Sorry! Thanks so much for the help!